# Jasmine and AngularJS - how to test a factory function when the function is used as a dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following simple factory that i would like write a unit test around.

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
       .module("math")
        .factory("addservice", [addTwoNumbers]);

    function addTwoNumbers(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    return { add: addTwoNumbers };
})();
```

This is what i have so far in my test spec.

```
    describe('adding two numbers', function () {
    var addService;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('math');
        inject(function ($injector) {
            addService = $injector.get('addservice');
        });
    });
    it('should add two numbers and get 2', function () {
        var result = addService.add(1, 1);
        expect(result).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

When trying to run this unit test i get TypeError: addService.add is not a function. I will note that i can get this to work if i change the factory declaration to the code seen below but we ran into a problem where minification was screwing up parameter names and changing them to a,b,c,etc. (when passing in $q, $http, and many other dependencies) and breaking the code so we moved to what is seen above. This is obviously a very basic example here which is why it is so frustrating on why i can't get this to work.

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
       .module("math")
       .factory('addservice', [function () {
       function addTwoNumbers(a, b) {
           return a + b;
       }
       return { add: addTwoNumbers };
   }
       ]); 
})();
```

It seems like I need to reference the addTwoNumbers function somehow but not sure how i would go about doing that. I'm probably missing something very obvious so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i figured out what was wrong with this example. It ends up if i refactored my factory a bit I could simply make a call in my unit test to the property twoNumbersAddedTogether after i get the reference to the factory itself. I've provided the new unit test and factory code below.

factory code

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("math")
    .factory("addservice", [addTwoNumbers]);

    function addTwoNumbers() {

        return {twoNumbersAddedTogether: dotheMath}

        function dotheMath(a,b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
})();
```

unit test code

```
describe('adding two numbers', function () {
var addService;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('math');
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_addservice_) {
    addService = _addservice_;

}));

it('should add two numbers', function () {
    var result = addService.twoNumbersAddedTogether(1, 1);
    expect(result).toBe(2);
});});
```